# using Joblib memory library with partial objects

Tags: python, caching, partial, joblib

I have a function with two parameters:

```
def foo(x,y):
   # some complicated math
   return result
```

and I define partials using the `functools` library:

```
f1 = partial(foo,1)
f2 = partial(foo,2)
```

Now I would like to use the `joblib.Memory` library to cache the results in disk to avoid re-computation.

```
from joblib import Memory
mem = Memory(cachedir = '/tmp')    
f1c = mem.cache(f1)
f2c = mem.cache(f2)
res1 = f1c(10)
res2 = f1c(10)
```

When I run the code, I get the warning:

```
JobLibCollisionWarning: Cannot detect name collisions
for function 'unknown
```

Also the results are not cached. Is there a way to use partial objects with Memory library?